# Django 2 different views in 2 different apps for same URL

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view `index` in app `A` and `index` in app `B`, both for url `/`. I want to use `A.views.index` for authenticated user and  `B.view.index` if user is Anonymous.

How can I achieve this? Perhaps add a views.py in `ProjectRoot/ProjectRoot/` and use it to forward to an app's views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a third view that only checks the user's status and then calls the right view:

```
import A.views
import B.views

def combined_index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """Call A.views.index if user is authenticated, otherwise B.views.index."""
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return A.views.index(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return B.views.index(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to make this optional based on whether B is in INSTALLED_APPS, simply do:

```
import A.views

from django.conf import settings

if 'B' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    import B.views
    def combined_index(...):
        # as above
else:
    combined_index = A.views.index
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways :

- Use same view and check if user is authenticated or not in the beginning of view.
- create dummy view. Create view decorator to use before this dummy view. In decorator check if user is authenticated or not and then return one of two views from decorator
- Use same view, just give one additional parameter to the view - template. And render different templateto different users.

Comment: Hi @Odif I can't use same view/app. The app `A` is standalone and app `B` is like an add on which can be removed by simply removing it in `settings.py` without breaking any functionality. Is there any way I can redirect to an app's view without declaring any namespace?

Comment: Well if this is the case, then you can register one more view to same address. Declare it before the other projects/views are included in settings.py/urls.py and work your magic from there.You can take the 2nd approach there. Create dummy view and if 2nd app is not registered (import fails for example) then return view from 1st app. If not then... follow what other logic is necessary

Answer (score 0):

> Use same view and check if user is authenticated or not in the beginning of view.

I think this is a natrual solution.

```
def login_view(request):
result = get_response_code('success')

# POST means user is logging in
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user and user.is_active:
        logger.info('Authenticate success for user ' + username)
        # Correct password, and the user is marked "active"
        auth.login(request, user)
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        else:
            return redirect('/admin')
    else:
        logger.info('Authenticate failed for user ' + username)
        result = get_response_code('auth_failed_invalid_username_or_password')
# Just show the login page
return render_to_response('account/login.html',
                          locals(),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```